# Linear-time algorithm for deciding triconnectivity?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, connectedness

The german site of wikipedia (Look at wikipedia k-zusammenhang) states that there
 are linear-time algorithms to decide whether a given undirected graph is 
 triconnected (Deleting any two vertices does not disconnect the graph).

Unfortunately, there is no link to any such algorithm, not even a description,
 which method is used. A necessary condition is, that every vertex has degree at
 least $3$ and that the graph is connected (which can be easily checked by hand).

- Does anyone know such an algorithm ?
- Is there an algorithm, which can be done by hand ?

Answer (score 1):

There is linear time algorithm due to Hopcroft and Tarjan for finding the biconnected components of a graph. There is an article on wikipedia (English).